# Loading CCITT T.6 with GDI+ Bitmap class

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I have an issue where the Bitmap class in C# does not load the CCITT T.6 Tiff files correctly, it will flip it so the height is the width and the width is the height.

Has anyone done these before and knows the correct method of handling them?

Edit:

Here is the code:

```
    Bitmap B = new Bitmap(@"C:\test2.tif");
    Debug.WriteLine(B.Width); //returns 1728
    Debug.WriteLine(B.Height); //returns 1127
```

When I display it in the .net picture box (SizeMode set to Normal) it also displays incorrectly (stretched). But if I open it with Windows Photo Viewer it displays correctly.

These are the tags available on the tiff file:

```
    SubFileType (1 Long): Page
    ImageWidth (1 Long): 1728
    ImageLength (1 Long): 1127
    BitsPerSample (1 Short): 1
    Compression (1 Short): Group 4 Fax (aka CCITT FAX4)
    Photometric (1 Short): MinIsWhite
    FillOrder (1 Short): Lsb2Msb
    StripOffsets (1 Long): 8
    SamplesPerPixel (1 Short): 1
    RowsPerStrip (1 Long): 1127
    StripByteCounts (1 Long): 14764
    XResolution (1 Rational): 204
    YResolution (1 Rational): 98
    Group3Options (1 Long): 5
    ResolutionUnit (1 Short): Inch
    PageNumber (2 Short): 0, 0
    Software (32 ASCII): Windows NT Fax Server           
    CleanFaxData (1 Short): 0
    ConsecutiveBadFaxLines (1 Short): 0
    37680 (5632 Undefined): 
    40003 (26 ASCII): U.S. Robotics 56K FAX EXT 
    40005 (1 ASCII):  
    40046 (1 Long): 1
    40047 (1 Long): 4
    40048 (1 Long): 256
    40049 (1 Long): 18
    40051 (1 SRational): 
    40052 (1 SRational): 
    40053 (1 Long): 2
```

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 1):

A TIFF can have a tag that defines its orientation of the data in the rows of the image.  This tag is called `TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION` in *LibTiff*.

Some values are:

- 1 = The 0th row represents the visual top of the image, and the 0th column represents the visual left-hand side.
- 5 = The 0th row represents the visual left-hand side of the image, and the 0th column represents the visual top.

According to this article:

- [TIFF Tag Orientation](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/orientation.html)

> Many readers ignore this tag.

I suspect the Microsoft .NET `Bitmap` class is one of these readers and your images include that tag.

Comment: Thanks for that. These tiff files don't seem to have the orientation flag on them. They must have another way that they calculate the width and height of which I am unsure, the properties available are: 254,
256,
257,
258,
259,
262,
266,
273,
277,
278,
279,
282,
283,
292,
296,
297,
327,
328,
37680,
40001,
40002,
40003,
40005,
40046,
40047,
40048,
40049,
40051,
40052,
40053. I have tried using the 256 and 257 properties (height and width) but they seem to just return what the Bitmap class Height and Width returns (which is seemingly incorrect).

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am having the same problem with RIGHTFAX images. The only hint I can find is that the DPI for vert/horz are specified differently. The problem is that once the image is saved DPI is pretty meaningless. The image is displayed squashed. Have you managed to solve this at all.
I have tried using LibTiff ReadRGBAImageOriented and also have the same problem there?